# i am working on flip image but it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
script type="text/javascript">    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/path/to/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".flip").flip({
                trigger: 'hover'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <scrip>
        $(function () {
            $(".flip").flip({
                trigger: 'hover',
                axis: 'x'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .flip
        {
            height: 199px;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .flip img
        {
            width: 300px;
            height: auto;
        }
        .flip .back
        {
            background: #2184cd;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="flip">
        <div class="front"> 
            <img src="images/pic/70.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <h3>
                Some Text in the Back!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

i have wrote following code for it but the code is not working it display image and text below i wantit to be flip 
Note :what should i do if i want front and background as image only instead of text.[This is the result of above code.]What i want is when i hover on image it will flip and display the text.Note what should i do if i want different image both the side !

Comment: Have your checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: script tag is wrong: `<scrip>`

Comment: Where is C# here?

Comment: How could you relate it with C# ?

Comment: i am working on asp.net C# so i added it..sorry it'smy mistkae

Comment: @HIt please reply

Comment: which css should i apply to bring image near in slick slider bcz my image is so far between two image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think this is your perfect answer.**

```css
.flip
        {
            height: 199px;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .flip img
        {
            width: 300px;
            height: auto;
        }
        .flip .back
        {
            background: #2184cd;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Flip/1.1.2/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $(".flip").flip({
      trigger: 'hover'
    });
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $(".flip").flip({
      trigger: 'hover',
      axis: 'y'
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="flip">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b8/d6/02/b8d60211137a9b9aca275adeb594d0c7.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b8/d6/02/b8d60211137a9b9aca275adeb594d0c7.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: what should i do if i want horizonatl filp? this is vertical filp can u please tell me for horizonatl flip??????https://www.ostraining.com/images/coding/jquery-flip/demo/ check this site and watch 1st demo i want like that please reply

Comment: Now this is horizontal flip, Please see above answer

Comment: thanks but i am done with dynamic image on slider but in slider there are many images and i want only one or two image should be flip at a time what should i do for it which css should i apply? @Hit

Comment: please  reply please

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it in fiddle with pure CSS and HTML. please take a look

```
go through this beside link http://jsfiddle.net/cjaLhdjo
```